# Save and restore specific tables

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, table

in an Oracle 11.2 Database, Enterprise Edition, we are running calculations divided into 3 different "modules". These modules can be started on their own, but not parallel, so in between users are able to confirm the calculations and proceed with the next step.

Now I want to find a proper way to "save" and "restore" the tables to allow "a rollback" to the definied start before the module.

I have read the Oracle-Documentation about [(garantueed) restore points](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmconfb.htm#BRADV83309) but i think its way too much. Within its time of usage the process is more or less exclusive, but not garantueed. So i cannot rollback the complete database.

I found some information about the [OracleWorkspaceManager](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/index-087067.html) but I am not sure if this tool would be something I could use.

Finally, I simply want to save and maybe restore 6 or 7 different tables. Is there an "easy" way to do this? Alternatively I am thinking of materialized views to store the information "before" each step. But that would create dependencies into the workflow I cannot image right now.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the Flashback table feature?

Comment: So you say a restorepoint is usable to restore a specific table (or more specific tables) independent of other tables, users or sessions (not on the specified tables) by using this command? The Documentation is stating some stuff about reusing the log files and i have to admit that i do not fully understand the process including the flashback_retention_target and other dependencies stated in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think flashback table is based on flashback database - AFAIK the main requirement is undo being available. You'll have to read the corresponding docs very carfully to know whether that's appropriate or not for your situation. Simply copying the table with CATS before you start (i.e. really old-fashion) might also be an option.

Comment: Using DataPump is a good way to do that.

Comment: Guaranteed restore points are just that, they will let you restore *everything* back to  that state. You cannot restore individual tables, it is at whole database level. In your case, you probably should think of fixing the application to perform required rollback (safe restartability). Other than that, you can still select data in individual tables as of a certain point (using flashback) and re-create that data. But is not very safe (to flashback individual tables) if you have substantial RI in your schema. I still think fixing application might turn out to be best solution if possible.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. The fix in making the process "rollbackable" is not possible. Each step runs around 10 hours. Doing this without commiting anything, is something where i would get the beloved "snapshot to old". I am working on 2 < N < 4 Million datarows, including foreign keys between the table i want to delete.

Comment: _i cannot edit my previous comment. sry_ I stick with the "individual backup" of the data between each step, since nothing looks really usefull. But still i cannot believe that oracle does not allow a simple feature (without sysdba) save this table, restore this table. thank you everyone for your help and time.

Comment: @resTive you should be able to save and restore without sysdba with proper privileges (as table owner?). if you can't, then you are missing privileges perhaps.

Comment: i still stick with MVs and until now it works quite satisfying. a bit slow, but this is not that important. thank you anyway, raj.

Answer (score 1):

IF you just want to be able to restore a few tables and the volume is not to high, why not just make copies of them?

You do need to set up good auditing and security around all your tables to prevent data loss, in the event that users did manual updates on tables that are going to be restored because of a process failure or something similar.

It could be that despite that failure, the user modifications are still needed and valid.
Best would be to prevent any user changes in the period where processes run that could cause the need for a restore.